# Variable Operators in PHP

Tags: php, operators

Given this example, how would I return the result of the equation rather than the equation itself as a string?

```
$operator = '+';
foreach($resultSet as $item){
    $result = $item[$this->orderField] . $operator . 1;
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: What is the real case led you to this question?

Comment: I needed to swap items in an array but maintain their keys and values. $item[$this->orderField] would be the current item, +/- 1 would be the item it would swap positions with. I have written an array_swap function, and combined with reko_t's method it produces something similar to array([1]=>'1', [0]=>'0', [2]=>'2') from array([0]=>'0', [1]=>'1', [2]=>'2').

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could make functions that wrap the operators, or for simplicity just use the [**bc**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension:

```
$operator = '+';
$operators = array(
  '+' => 'bcadd',
  '-' => 'bcsub',
  '*' => 'bcmul',
  '/' => 'bcdiv'
);

foreach($resultSet as $item){
    $result = call_user_func($operators[$operator], $item[$this->orderField], 1);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Use an arbitrary precision math library to perform regular math? Looks kind of quirky...

Comment: Develop with extensibility in mind Alvaro... Who says the same function may not need to perform precision mathematics?

Comment: The performance in a situation like this is absolutely negligible in most cases. Ever heard of the saying premature optimization is the root of all evil? ;) Write clean, easy-to-understand and maintainable code and optimize if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

To achieve exactly that, you can use `create_function`

```
$operator = '+';
$func = create_function('$a,$b', "return \$a $operator \$b;");
foreach($resultSet as $item){
    $result = $func($item, 1);
    echo $result;
}
```

A cleaner solution is possible with lambdas (php5.3 required)

```
$func = function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };
foreach($resultSet as $item){
    $result = $func($item, 1);
    echo $result;
}
```

See also array_sum, array_reduce

Advanced example with array_reduce and lambdas

```
$ary = array(
    array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 91),
    array('foo' => 2, 'bar' => 92),
    array('foo' => 3, 'bar' => 93),
    array('foo' => 4, 'bar' => 94),
    array('foo' => 5, 'bar' => 95),
);

$sumOfFoos = array_reduce($ary, 
    function($val, $item) { return $val + $item['foo']; } 
);
$sumOfBars = array_reduce($ary, 
    function($val, $item) { return $val + $item['bar']; } 
);
```

The main point is, that instead of 'variable operators' (which is not possible in php), you should rather use variable functions (which is possible and much more flexible).

Comment: it will eval my _code_ but not _variables_, which is the key difference.

Comment: But either $operator is an arbitrary variable, too, or you don't need create\_function (like in reko\_t's answer), do you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but it's generally a bad idea, since it's a major potential security hole (be careful you're not allowing visitors to run arbitrary code!).

It can also result in hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is eval(). However, in this precise example I would just hard-code the possible operations:

```
<?php

$operator = '+';
foreach($resultSet as $item){
    switch($operator){
        case '+':
            $result = $item[$this->orderField] + 1;
            break;
    }
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the eval function of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$operator = '+';
foreach($resultSet as $item){
    $result = $item[$this->orderField] . $operator . 1;
    eval("\$result = \"$result\";");
    echo $result;
}
```