# Build condition comparison for if statement

Tags: php, dynamic, comparison, if-statement

Is this possible?

```
$var_1 = 1;
$var_2 = 10;
$comparison = '>';

if($var_1 $comparison $var_2) {
    // do something...
}
```

The syntax right now is not valid but is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552052/variable-operators-in-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not natively (except of course with `eval`). You will need to evaluate the various expressions yourself. Build a wrapper function and use a `switch` statement. Or for non-expression comparisons a simple map:

```
$var_1 = 1;
$var_2 = 10;
$comparison = '>';

$map = array(
    ">" => $var_1 > $var_2,
    "<" => $var_1 < $var_2,
    "==" => $var_1 == $var_2,
    "!=" => $var_1 != $var_2,
);

if($map[$comparison]) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with

```
if (eval("{$var_1} {$comparison} {$var_2}")) {
```

But `eval` is strongly discouraged, so do this only if you can't achieve desired result otherwise

**EDIT**
As @mario noted, until PHP 5.3 this doesn't work. In 5.3 it does. So for older versions it should be

```
if (eval("return {$var_1} {$comparison} {$var_2};")) {
```

Comment: if you do use eval, and `comparison` is user input, make sure to check it against a white list of possible comparisons

Comment: Your eval is not going to function without `return` and the closing `;` semicolon. `eval` only works on statements, not expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should use `eval()`. As like in other programming languages, PHP’s `eval()` is also powerful and dangerous — be careful.

If you write something like the following code:

```
if (eval("$var_1 $comparison $var_2")) {
    // ...
}
```

It won’t work. Because PHP’s `eval()` *doesn’t evaluate an **expression***, but *just execute a **statement***. So you should do like:

```
eval("\$condition = $var_1 $comparison $var_2;"); // semicolon required!
if ($condition) {
    // ...
}
```

It would work well except `$var_1` or `$var_2` is not number. For example, if `$var_1` is a string like `'hello'`, the code `eval()` executes becomes:

```
eval("\$condition = hello > 2;");
```

To avoid breaking this code, you should escape dollar signs of `$var_1` and `$var_2`:

```
eval("\$condition = \$var_1 $comparison \$var_2;"); // don't escape $comparison's.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible without the hackish use of an eval statement. You could of course wrap simply test what comparison is being used within another if statement.

```
if($comparison == '>' && $var_1 > $var_2)
    //Do something
elseif($comparison == '<' && $var_1 < $var_2)
    //Do something, and so on
```

The eval method should work too if you build you code into an a string.

```
if(eval("$var_1 $comparison $var_2")) //Do something
```

But the first method is probably far more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a few functions like isGreaterThan($arg1, $arg2), isLessThan($arg1, $arg2), and then store the name of the function you want in the variable $comparison. Then you would use call_user_func_array() when you want to use it.  Like so :

```
function isGreaterThan($val1, $val2) {
    return $val1 > $val2;
}

/////////////

$var_1 = 1;
$var_2 = 10;
$comparison = "isGreaterThan";

if(call_user_func_array($comparison, array($var_1, var_2))) {
    //do something
}
```

Sounds like you've got a few options.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## make the string a conditional, returning a value if true or false

## short form if statement

```
$var_1 = 1;
$var_2 = 10;
$comparison = '>=';

eval("\$b=$var_1 $comparison $var_2?1:0;");

if ($b) {
//do something
}
```