# how do i do the calculation with a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

Ok so i have 3 variables

```
 $real_price = 33.00;
 $real_option = 13.00;
 $option_value['price_prefix'] = "-";
 $real_total = $real_price $option_value['price_prefix'] $real_option;
```

how come i cant do line 4

I need `$real_total` to be `20.00`

i get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Comment: Why should this work? How can the PHP interpreter know what to do when you put three variables in a row?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552052/variable-operators-in-php

Comment: @str: The solution provided there is a bad solution.

Comment: @Rok Kralj No, it's a good solution that only allows a certain list of operators to be used.

Comment: @Igor: Refresh page more often. Solution listed there is problematic from the point of relying on unstandard extension & performance hit.

Comment: @Rok Kralj If you edit your answer (perhaps indent the code, or something), I will be able to remove my downvote.

Comment: @Rok Kralj What do you mean by "the point of relying on unstandard extension & performance hit"?

Comment: Doing regular arithmetics, instead of bcmath is much faster. Also bcmath didn't exist in <PHP4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $real_price = 33.00;
 $real_option = 13.00;
 $option_value['price_prefix'] = "-";
 eval('$real_total = $real_price '.$option_value['price_prefix'].' $real_option');
```

Althrough I don't recommend doing it like that. Do it like this:

```
 $real_price = 33.00;
 $real_option = 13.00;
 $option_value['price_prefix'] = "-";
switch($option_value['price_prefix']) {
case '+': $real_total=$real_price+$real_option; break;
case '-': $real_total=$real_price-$real_option; break;
case '*': $real_total=$real_price*$real_option; break;
}
```

Comment: For a quick answer :) I wanted to present how can OP achieve result his way, but presenting nicer alternative.

Comment: The hero with downvote shall present his reasons for doing so.

Comment: I have removed the downvote because you edited the answer and now it's all better. Edit: Oops, it seems that I can't remove my downvote. Sorry.