# php sum with add symbol as variable

Tags: php

I have this variable

```
$option_value['price'] = 2
$option_value['price_prefix'] = +
$this->data['price2'] = 3
```

I have tried to make sum from it like this

```
$price = $option_value['price'].''.$option_value['price_prefix'].''.$this->data['price2'];
echo $price
```

but the result is 2. What I want is 5.

Prease help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293087/how-do-i-do-the-calculation-with-a-variable-in-php

Comment: If your set of variables was anywhere near correct (missing `;`'s, + should be in quotes) then you'd get `2+3` as the output.

Comment: this code has an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that the prefix is always either `+` or `-`, something like this should do the trick (I've changed the variable names for the sake of readability):

```
$price = 2;
$prefix = "+";
$price2 = 3;

$total = $price + ($prefix.$price2);
```

This concatenates the prefix and the second price to `"+3"` which will then be cast implicitly to an integer for the addition with the first price. The parentheses make sure that the concatenation is done before the addition. Otherwise the addition would precede and that would lead to concatenation rather than addition.

Comment: awesome. Thanks friend

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
<?php

$option_value['price'] = 2;
$option_value['price_prefix'] = '+';
$option_value['price2'] = 3;

$price = $option_value['price']+$option_value['price_prefix']+$option_value['price2'];
echo $price; 

?>
```

Comment: it don't work. When I change $option_value['price_prefix'] = '-'; the result still the same