# Raw output of PHP sum, multiplication, division, subtraction

Tags: php

I am trying this code which should perform +, _, x, / but i am getting raw output instead of sum, multiplaction, division, subtraction. here is my code.

```
if($randf=='1'){$fac='+';}
if($randf=='2'){$fac='-';}
if($randf=='3'){$fac='*';}
if($randf=='4'){$fac='/';}

$ran1=rand(1,100);
$ran2=rand(1,500);
$cans=$ran1.$fac.$ran2;

echo $cans;
```

but it outputs something like this

```
10+45
```

instead of 55. can u please tell where i am doing mistake.

In addition to that, I am trying to perform some filtering function in post. When users submit data in post I am trying to match with some value and then updating to database. Unfortunately, that also fails and always gives 0 as output.

```
if ($ans2==$ans1)
{
    $marks==1;
}
else {
    $marks=0;
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLEA () VALUES ()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll not ask why you are doing it.. there are more interesting aproaches like our colleagues pointed.

You can interpret a string that contain the operation as a matematical one like this:

```
<?
$a = "10+45";
$c = 0;
eval("\$c = $a;");
echo $c; //echoes 55
?>
```

The eval function will execute the string as a PHP command and $c will have the result.

Comment: you rocks boss i am comparing post values before storing to databaseif ($ans2==$ans1) { $marks==1; } else { $marks=0; } mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLEA () VALUES ()")

Comment: I'm glad I could help.
Take care of that query. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're simply treating the numbers and the operators as strings and concatenating them. If you really want to design your code like that, you can use [eval()](https://www.php.net/eval), so your last line would be `echo eval($cans);`

Otherwise, a better way to do this is to use a `switch` like @Nouphal.M suggested in his answer.

Note: Keep in mind that using `eval()` is more expensive than simply doing the arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating the numbers and operators as strings not actually evaluating them so the operation never gets performed. The following post might help you.

[Variable Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552052/variable-operators-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. `"An operator is something that takes one or more values and yields another value"`. You cannot consider them as string or either typecast them.  Using `eval` function is not recommended. see the caution [here](https://www.php.net/eval)
You have to try something like this

```
$ran1=rand(1,100);
$ran2=rand(1,500);
$cans =0;
switch($randf){
   case "1": 
          $cans= $ran1+$ran2;
   break;
  .....
} 

return $cans;
```

[Updated part]

The use of mysql_* functions are deprecated, so you should try using mysqli or PDO.
Your query is wrong.

The syntax of an insert query is

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (field1,field2,...) VALUES (value1,value2,...)
```

Where your_table_name is your table name, field1,field2.. are the table field names for which you want to save values value1,value2 to be stored ***respectively***.

Comment: thanks i was doing mistake and right way is to do with switch  but in this case where i am doing mistake any idea i am comparing post values before storing to databaseif ($ans2==$ans1)
{
    $marks==1;
}
else {
    $marks=0;
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLEA () VALUES ()")